# Why doesn't findViewById() in an Activity return the user typed value?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm creating an Android app where the scenario is User Sign Up and upon clicking "Sign Up" button , the app sends data to REST API.

**activity_sign_up_login.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logIn"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/signUp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobNum" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobNum"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryCode" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SignUp.java**

```
    public class SignUpLogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final ConnectionStatus connectionStatus = new ConnectionStatus(getApplicationContext());
            if(!connectionStatus.isOnline()){
                connectionStatus.displayMobileDataSettingsDialog(this, getApplicationContext());
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_log_in);


            final TextView mobNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobNum);
            final TextView passwordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
            Button signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);


            final String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            final String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();

            signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password)){
                        Intent checkSignUpStatusIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrossCheckSignUpService.class);
                        checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                        checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmMobileNumber", mobNumber);
                        checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmPassword", password);
                        startService(checkSignUpStatusIntent);
                        connectionStatus.showProgress();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

private boolean validateInputFields(String mobNum, String password){
        StringBuffer errors = new StringBuffer();
        int count = 0;
        boolean hasError = false;
        if(mobNum == null || mobNum.isEmpty()){
            ++count;
            errors.append(count + ") Please enter your mobile number");
            errors.append('\n');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(password == null || password.isEmpty()){
            //cEmail field is empty
            ++count;
            errors.append(count + ") Please enter a password");
            errors.append('\n');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(hasError){
            Toast.makeText(this, errors.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Inside the onClick(), the values are empty, despite user entering the values.

1. Why is that?
2. How to fix it?

Please answer inline.

PS:

I cannot remove final for textView variables above `.setOnClickListener`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `mobNumber` and `password` from inside the `onClick()` method:

```
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();

            if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password)){
                Intent checkSignUpStatusIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrossCheckSignUpService.class);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmMobileNumber", mobNumber);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmPassword", password);
                startService(checkSignUpStatusIntent);
                connectionStatus.showProgress();
            }
        }
    });
```

### Edit

There is no need to declare your variables as final if you are using them like this

```
  TextView mobNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobNum);
  TextView passwordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

and inside `onClick()`

```
String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();
```

### Edit 2

I just found your problem.

In your validateInputFields method you are passing 2 strings, mobNum and password, in your if statement you are trying passing 2 strings to the method, that's ok `if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password))...` But, the two strings you are trying to pass through the method are outside your `onClick()` so, those values can't be reached and your `validateInputFields()` method is not getting anything to work.

### Edit 3

I just see that you have this 2 editTexts in your xml

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobNum" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobNum"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryCode" />
```

but your reference states two textViews

```
 TextView mobNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobNum);
 TextView passwordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

you should add two textViews to your xml, or change that `TextView mobNumb....` to

```
EditText mobNumber...
```

Like this

```
 EditText mobNumberTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobNum);
 EditText passwordTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: I'm getting `variable 'mobNumberTextView' is accessed from within Inner class, needs to be declared final `  , if I remove final for variables outside setOnClickListener.

Comment: But, does making the variable mobNumberTextView as final before user entering a value, and hence it is always null??

Comment: you can remove the final from inside the onClick and the final from your textViews, ther is no need to still have them

Comment: I cannot remove final for textViews.

Comment: can you edit your question and let us know where you are using those final variables ?

Comment: in this method validateInputFields you are usign the values from the edittext to validate them ? if that is true, you should declare the edittext in that method in order to get the values, can you please post the code of that method ? , thanks

Comment: please edit your question with all your SignUpLogIn code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to get value after in onClick.

**Why ?**

`findViewById` is used to bind your views, after binding you'r calling `getText` immediately that's why it is empty.

Replace your code with this

```
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();

            if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password)){
                Intent checkSignUpStatusIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrossCheckSignUpService.class);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmMobileNumber", mobNumber);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmPassword", password);
                startService(checkSignUpStatusIntent);
                connectionStatus.showProgress();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The words **final** are no longer needed inside `onClick`!

Comment: Right...There is no need of final. We have to make outer class variable final if used in inner class.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani I'm getting variable 'mobNumberTextView' is accessed from within Inner class, needs to be declared final , if I remove final for variables outside setOnClickListener.

Comment: @SpandanaKrishnan I just updated my answer. No need to declare variable final.

Answer (score 0):

Please get the Value from EditText inside the onClickListener

```
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            final String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();
            if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password)){
                Intent checkSignUpStatusIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrossCheckSignUpService.class);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmMobileNumber", mobNumber);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmPassword", password);
                startService(checkSignUpStatusIntent);
                connectionStatus.showProgress();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value from `edittext`  inside your  **`signUp.setOnClickListener`**

```
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String mobNumber = mobNumberTextView.getText().toString();
             String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();

            if(!validateInputFields(mobNumber, password)){
                Intent checkSignUpStatusIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrossCheckSignUpService.class);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("countryCode", countryCode);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmMobileNumber", mobNumber);
                checkSignUpStatusIntent.putExtra("confirmPassword", password);
                startService(checkSignUpStatusIntent);
                connectionStatus.showProgress();
            }
        }
    });
```